# How can I write a query to get the number occurrence of each calendar month in a date range

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11gr2

I have a table with columns "start_date" and "end_date" and I'm trying to summarize the dates by splitting them across the period. For example, if start and end dates are '01-JAN-2017' and '01-MAR-2018' respectively, then the query should return each months as different fields/columns. Also, I want to see the number of appearance/occurence made by each month during the period  i.e. months like JAN, FEB and MAR should have a value of 2 since they occured twice during the period between '01-JAN-2017' and '01-MAR-2018'.

for example, if start_date = '01-JAN-2018' and end_date = '31-MAR-2019', then the output should be:

```
 jan | feb | mar | apr | may | jun | jul | aug | sep | oct | nov | dec
-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----
   2 |   2 |   2 |   1 |   1 |   1 |   1 |   1 |   1 |   1 |   1 |   1
```

Comment: I don't have any Oracle experience, but you may want to consider doing this in a table-valued function rather than a query. On a high-level, I'd start by taking the total number of months, and iterate a loop that many times to count the occurrences of each month in the range.

Comment: In your example, start_date and end_date are strings, not dates. Always use `to_date(...)` when you create dates from strings, with the corresponding date format model as the second argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started. This was an example I had to do to split employee check-in and check-out times across the day, but the concept is similar. We synthesize the intermediate data, and then pivot into the rows

```
SQL> create table t
  2  ( emp int,
  3    in_time date,
  4    out_time date );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL>
SQL> insert into t values (1, trunc(sysdate)+1.5/24,   trunc(sysdate)+3.5/24);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t values (1, trunc(sysdate)+5.4/24,   trunc(sysdate)+9.5/24);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t values (1, trunc(sysdate)+10/24,   trunc(sysdate)+11/24);

1 row created.

SQL>
SQL> insert into t values (2, trunc(sysdate)+2.2/24,   trunc(sysdate)+3.5/24);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t values (2, trunc(sysdate)+5/24,   trunc(sysdate)+7/24);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t values (2, trunc(sysdate)+10.7/24,   trunc(sysdate)+11.2/24);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t values (2, trunc(sysdate)+9.2/24,   trunc(sysdate)+9.4/24);

1 row created.

SQL>
SQL> @longdate

Session altered.

SQL>
SQL> select
  2       emp,
  3       in_time,
  4       out_time,
  5       to_number(to_char(in_time,'HH24')) as in_hr,
  6       to_number(to_char(out_time,'HH24')) as out_hr,
  7       to_number(to_char(in_time,'MI')) as in_min,
  8       to_number(to_char(out_time,'MI')) as out_min
  9    from t;

       EMP IN_TIME             OUT_TIME                 IN_HR     OUT_HR     IN_MIN    OUT_MIN
---------- ------------------- ------------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1 12/07/2019 01:30:00 12/07/2019 03:30:00          1          3         30         30
         1 12/07/2019 05:24:00 12/07/2019 09:30:00          5          9         24         30
         1 12/07/2019 10:00:00 12/07/2019 11:00:00         10         11          0          0
         2 12/07/2019 02:12:00 12/07/2019 03:30:00          2          3         12         30
         2 12/07/2019 05:00:00 12/07/2019 07:00:00          5          7          0          0
         2 12/07/2019 10:42:00 12/07/2019 11:12:00         10         11         42         12
         2 12/07/2019 09:12:00 12/07/2019 09:24:00          9          9         12         24

7 rows selected.

SQL>
SQL> with t_extended as
  2  ( select
  3       emp,
  4       in_time,
  5       out_time,
  6       to_number(to_char(in_time,'HH24')) as in_hr,
  7       to_number(to_char(out_time,'HH24')) as out_hr,
  8       to_number(to_char(in_time,'MI')) as in_min,
  9       to_number(to_char(out_time,'MI')) as out_min
 10    from t
 11  ),
 12  hr_of_day as
 13    ( select level-1 hr from dual connect by level <= 24 )
 14  select
 15    e.emp,
 16    e.in_time,
 17    e.out_time,
 18    h.hr,
 19    case
 20      -- totally outside range
 21      when in_hr > hr then 0
 22      when out_hr < hr then 0
 23      -- less than 1 hour
 24      when in_hr = hr and out_hr = hr then  out_min - in_min
 25      -- ends on hour
 26      when in_hr < hr and out_hr = hr then  out_min
 27      -- start on hour
 28      when in_hr = hr and out_hr > hr then 60 - in_min
 29      -- contained
 30      when in_hr < hr and out_hr > hr then 60
 31    end dur
 32  from t_extended e, hr_of_day h
 33  order by 1,2,4;

       EMP IN_TIME             OUT_TIME                    HR        DUR
---------- ------------------- ------------------- ---------- ----------
         1 12/07/2019 01:30:00 12/07/2019 03:30:00          0          0
         1 12/07/2019 01:30:00 12/07/2019 03:30:00          1         30
         1 12/07/2019 01:30:00 12/07/2019 03:30:00          2         60
         1 12/07/2019 01:30:00 12/07/2019 03:30:00          3         30
         1 12/07/2019 01:30:00 12/07/2019 03:30:00          4          0
         1 12/07/2019 01:30:00 12/07/2019 03:30:00          5          0
         1 12/07/2019 01:30:00 12/07/2019 03:30:00          6          0
         1 12/07/2019 01:30:00 12/07/2019 03:30:00          7          0
         1 12/07/2019 01:30:00 12/07/2019 03:30:00          8          0
         1 12/07/2019 01:30:00 12/07/2019 03:30:00          9          0
         1 12/07/2019 01:30:00 12/07/2019 03:30:00         10          0
         1 12/07/2019 01:30:00 12/07/2019 03:30:00         11          0
         1 12/07/2019 01:30:00 12/07/2019 03:30:00         12          0
         1 12/07/2019 01:30:00 12/07/2019 03:30:00         13          0
         1 12/07/2019 01:30:00 12/07/2019 03:30:00         14          0
         1 12/07/2019 01:30:00 12/07/2019 03:30:00         15          0
         1 12/07/2019 01:30:00 12/07/2019 03:30:00         16          0
         1 12/07/2019 01:30:00 12/07/2019 03:30:00         17          0
         1 12/07/2019 01:30:00 12/07/2019 03:30:00         18          0
         1 12/07/2019 01:30:00 12/07/2019 03:30:00         19          0
         1 12/07/2019 01:30:00 12/07/2019 03:30:00         20          0
         1 12/07/2019 01:30:00 12/07/2019 03:30:00         21          0
         1 12/07/2019 01:30:00 12/07/2019 03:30:00         22          0
         1 12/07/2019 01:30:00 12/07/2019 03:30:00         23          0
         1 12/07/2019 05:24:00 12/07/2019 09:30:00          0          0
         1 12/07/2019 05:24:00 12/07/2019 09:30:00          1          0
         1 12/07/2019 05:24:00 12/07/2019 09:30:00          2          0
         1 12/07/2019 05:24:00 12/07/2019 09:30:00          3          0
         1 12/07/2019 05:24:00 12/07/2019 09:30:00          4          0
         1 12/07/2019 05:24:00 12/07/2019 09:30:00          5         36
         1 12/07/2019 05:24:00 12/07/2019 09:30:00          6         60
         1 12/07/2019 05:24:00 12/07/2019 09:30:00          7         60
         1 12/07/2019 05:24:00 12/07/2019 09:30:00          8         60
         1 12/07/2019 05:24:00 12/07/2019 09:30:00          9         30
         1 12/07/2019 05:24:00 12/07/2019 09:30:00         10          0
         1 12/07/2019 05:24:00 12/07/2019 09:30:00         11          0
         1 12/07/2019 05:24:00 12/07/2019 09:30:00         12          0
         1 12/07/2019 05:24:00 12/07/2019 09:30:00         13          0
         1 12/07/2019 05:24:00 12/07/2019 09:30:00         14          0
         1 12/07/2019 05:24:00 12/07/2019 09:30:00         15          0
         1 12/07/2019 05:24:00 12/07/2019 09:30:00         16          0
         1 12/07/2019 05:24:00 12/07/2019 09:30:00         17          0
         1 12/07/2019 05:24:00 12/07/2019 09:30:00         18          0
         1 12/07/2019 05:24:00 12/07/2019 09:30:00         19          0
         1 12/07/2019 05:24:00 12/07/2019 09:30:00         20          0
         1 12/07/2019 05:24:00 12/07/2019 09:30:00         21          0
         1 12/07/2019 05:24:00 12/07/2019 09:30:00         22          0
         1 12/07/2019 05:24:00 12/07/2019 09:30:00         23          0
         1 12/07/2019 10:00:00 12/07/2019 11:00:00          0          0
         1 12/07/2019 10:00:00 12/07/2019 11:00:00          1          0
         1 12/07/2019 10:00:00 12/07/2019 11:00:00          2          0
         1 12/07/2019 10:00:00 12/07/2019 11:00:00          3          0
         1 12/07/2019 10:00:00 12/07/2019 11:00:00          4          0
         1 12/07/2019 10:00:00 12/07/2019 11:00:00          5          0
         1 12/07/2019 10:00:00 12/07/2019 11:00:00          6          0
         1 12/07/2019 10:00:00 12/07/2019 11:00:00          7          0
         1 12/07/2019 10:00:00 12/07/2019 11:00:00          8          0
         1 12/07/2019 10:00:00 12/07/2019 11:00:00          9          0
         1 12/07/2019 10:00:00 12/07/2019 11:00:00         10         60
         1 12/07/2019 10:00:00 12/07/2019 11:00:00         11          0
         1 12/07/2019 10:00:00 12/07/2019 11:00:00         12          0
         1 12/07/2019 10:00:00 12/07/2019 11:00:00         13          0
         1 12/07/2019 10:00:00 12/07/2019 11:00:00         14          0
         1 12/07/2019 10:00:00 12/07/2019 11:00:00         15          0
         1 12/07/2019 10:00:00 12/07/2019 11:00:00         16          0
         1 12/07/2019 10:00:00 12/07/2019 11:00:00         17          0
         1 12/07/2019 10:00:00 12/07/2019 11:00:00         18          0
         1 12/07/2019 10:00:00 12/07/2019 11:00:00         19          0
         1 12/07/2019 10:00:00 12/07/2019 11:00:00         20          0
         1 12/07/2019 10:00:00 12/07/2019 11:00:00         21          0
         1 12/07/2019 10:00:00 12/07/2019 11:00:00         22          0
         1 12/07/2019 10:00:00 12/07/2019 11:00:00         23          0
         2 12/07/2019 02:12:00 12/07/2019 03:30:00          0          0
         2 12/07/2019 02:12:00 12/07/2019 03:30:00          1          0
         2 12/07/2019 02:12:00 12/07/2019 03:30:00          2         48
         2 12/07/2019 02:12:00 12/07/2019 03:30:00          3         30
         2 12/07/2019 02:12:00 12/07/2019 03:30:00          4          0
         2 12/07/2019 02:12:00 12/07/2019 03:30:00          5          0
         2 12/07/2019 02:12:00 12/07/2019 03:30:00          6          0
         2 12/07/2019 02:12:00 12/07/2019 03:30:00          7          0
         2 12/07/2019 02:12:00 12/07/2019 03:30:00          8          0
         2 12/07/2019 02:12:00 12/07/2019 03:30:00          9          0
         2 12/07/2019 02:12:00 12/07/2019 03:30:00         10          0
         2 12/07/2019 02:12:00 12/07/2019 03:30:00         11          0
         2 12/07/2019 02:12:00 12/07/2019 03:30:00         12          0
         2 12/07/2019 02:12:00 12/07/2019 03:30:00         13          0
         2 12/07/2019 02:12:00 12/07/2019 03:30:00         14          0
         2 12/07/2019 02:12:00 12/07/2019 03:30:00         15          0
         2 12/07/2019 02:12:00 12/07/2019 03:30:00         16          0
         2 12/07/2019 02:12:00 12/07/2019 03:30:00         17          0
         2 12/07/2019 02:12:00 12/07/2019 03:30:00         18          0
         2 12/07/2019 02:12:00 12/07/2019 03:30:00         19          0
         2 12/07/2019 02:12:00 12/07/2019 03:30:00         20          0
         2 12/07/2019 02:12:00 12/07/2019 03:30:00         21          0
         2 12/07/2019 02:12:00 12/07/2019 03:30:00         22          0
         2 12/07/2019 02:12:00 12/07/2019 03:30:00         23          0

       EMP IN_TIME             OUT_TIME                    HR        DUR
---------- ------------------- ------------------- ---------- ----------
         2 12/07/2019 05:00:00 12/07/2019 07:00:00          0          0
         2 12/07/2019 05:00:00 12/07/2019 07:00:00          1          0
         2 12/07/2019 05:00:00 12/07/2019 07:00:00          2          0
         2 12/07/2019 05:00:00 12/07/2019 07:00:00          3          0
         2 12/07/2019 05:00:00 12/07/2019 07:00:00          4          0
         2 12/07/2019 05:00:00 12/07/2019 07:00:00          5         60
         2 12/07/2019 05:00:00 12/07/2019 07:00:00          6         60
         2 12/07/2019 05:00:00 12/07/2019 07:00:00          7          0
         2 12/07/2019 05:00:00 12/07/2019 07:00:00          8          0
         2 12/07/2019 05:00:00 12/07/2019 07:00:00          9          0
         2 12/07/2019 05:00:00 12/07/2019 07:00:00         10          0
         2 12/07/2019 05:00:00 12/07/2019 07:00:00         11          0
         2 12/07/2019 05:00:00 12/07/2019 07:00:00         12          0
         2 12/07/2019 05:00:00 12/07/2019 07:00:00         13          0
         2 12/07/2019 05:00:00 12/07/2019 07:00:00         14          0
         2 12/07/2019 05:00:00 12/07/2019 07:00:00         15          0
         2 12/07/2019 05:00:00 12/07/2019 07:00:00         16          0
         2 12/07/2019 05:00:00 12/07/2019 07:00:00         17          0
         2 12/07/2019 05:00:00 12/07/2019 07:00:00         18          0
         2 12/07/2019 05:00:00 12/07/2019 07:00:00         19          0
         2 12/07/2019 05:00:00 12/07/2019 07:00:00         20          0
         2 12/07/2019 05:00:00 12/07/2019 07:00:00         21          0
         2 12/07/2019 05:00:00 12/07/2019 07:00:00         22          0
         2 12/07/2019 05:00:00 12/07/2019 07:00:00         23          0
         2 12/07/2019 09:12:00 12/07/2019 09:24:00          0          0
         2 12/07/2019 09:12:00 12/07/2019 09:24:00          1          0
         2 12/07/2019 09:12:00 12/07/2019 09:24:00          2          0
         2 12/07/2019 09:12:00 12/07/2019 09:24:00          3          0
         2 12/07/2019 09:12:00 12/07/2019 09:24:00          4          0
         2 12/07/2019 09:12:00 12/07/2019 09:24:00          5          0
         2 12/07/2019 09:12:00 12/07/2019 09:24:00          6          0
         2 12/07/2019 09:12:00 12/07/2019 09:24:00          7          0
         2 12/07/2019 09:12:00 12/07/2019 09:24:00          8          0
         2 12/07/2019 09:12:00 12/07/2019 09:24:00          9         12
         2 12/07/2019 09:12:00 12/07/2019 09:24:00         10          0
         2 12/07/2019 09:12:00 12/07/2019 09:24:00         11          0
         2 12/07/2019 09:12:00 12/07/2019 09:24:00         12          0
         2 12/07/2019 09:12:00 12/07/2019 09:24:00         13          0
         2 12/07/2019 09:12:00 12/07/2019 09:24:00         14          0
         2 12/07/2019 09:12:00 12/07/2019 09:24:00         15          0
         2 12/07/2019 09:12:00 12/07/2019 09:24:00         16          0
         2 12/07/2019 09:12:00 12/07/2019 09:24:00         17          0
         2 12/07/2019 09:12:00 12/07/2019 09:24:00         18          0
         2 12/07/2019 09:12:00 12/07/2019 09:24:00         19          0
         2 12/07/2019 09:12:00 12/07/2019 09:24:00         20          0
         2 12/07/2019 09:12:00 12/07/2019 09:24:00         21          0
         2 12/07/2019 09:12:00 12/07/2019 09:24:00         22          0
         2 12/07/2019 09:12:00 12/07/2019 09:24:00         23          0
         2 12/07/2019 10:42:00 12/07/2019 11:12:00          0          0
         2 12/07/2019 10:42:00 12/07/2019 11:12:00          1          0
         2 12/07/2019 10:42:00 12/07/2019 11:12:00          2          0
         2 12/07/2019 10:42:00 12/07/2019 11:12:00          3          0
         2 12/07/2019 10:42:00 12/07/2019 11:12:00          4          0
         2 12/07/2019 10:42:00 12/07/2019 11:12:00          5          0
         2 12/07/2019 10:42:00 12/07/2019 11:12:00          6          0
         2 12/07/2019 10:42:00 12/07/2019 11:12:00          7          0
         2 12/07/2019 10:42:00 12/07/2019 11:12:00          8          0
         2 12/07/2019 10:42:00 12/07/2019 11:12:00          9          0
         2 12/07/2019 10:42:00 12/07/2019 11:12:00         10         18
         2 12/07/2019 10:42:00 12/07/2019 11:12:00         11         12
         2 12/07/2019 10:42:00 12/07/2019 11:12:00         12          0
         2 12/07/2019 10:42:00 12/07/2019 11:12:00         13          0
         2 12/07/2019 10:42:00 12/07/2019 11:12:00         14          0
         2 12/07/2019 10:42:00 12/07/2019 11:12:00         15          0
         2 12/07/2019 10:42:00 12/07/2019 11:12:00         16          0
         2 12/07/2019 10:42:00 12/07/2019 11:12:00         17          0
         2 12/07/2019 10:42:00 12/07/2019 11:12:00         18          0
         2 12/07/2019 10:42:00 12/07/2019 11:12:00         19          0
         2 12/07/2019 10:42:00 12/07/2019 11:12:00         20          0
         2 12/07/2019 10:42:00 12/07/2019 11:12:00         21          0
         2 12/07/2019 10:42:00 12/07/2019 11:12:00         22          0
         2 12/07/2019 10:42:00 12/07/2019 11:12:00         23          0

168 rows selected.

SQL>
SQL> with t_extended as
  2  ( select
  3       emp,
  4       in_time,
  5       out_time,
  6       to_number(to_char(in_time,'HH24')) as in_hr,
  7       to_number(to_char(out_time,'HH24')) as out_hr,
  8       to_number(to_char(in_time,'MI')) as in_min,
  9       to_number(to_char(out_time,'MI')) as out_min
 10    from t
 11  ),
 12  hr_of_day as
 13    ( select level-1 hr from dual connect by level <= 24 ),
 14  raw_data as (
 15  select
 16    e.emp,
 17    e.in_time,
 18    e.out_time,
 19    h.hr,
 20    case
 21      -- totally outside range
 22      when in_hr > hr then 0
 23      when out_hr < hr then 0
 24      -- less than 1 hour
 25      when in_hr = hr and out_hr = hr then  out_min - in_min
 26      -- ends on hour
 27      when in_hr < hr and out_hr = hr then  out_min
 28      -- start on hour
 29      when in_hr = hr and out_hr > hr then 60 - in_min
 30      -- contained
 31      when in_hr < hr and out_hr > hr then 60
 32    end dur
 33  from t_extended e, hr_of_day h
 34  --order by 1,2,4
 35  )
 36  select *
 37  from  ( select emp, hr, dur from raw_data )
 38  pivot ( sum(dur) as t for (hr) in ( 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23))
 39  /

       EMP        0_T        1_T        2_T        3_T        4_T        5_T        6_T        7_T        8_T        9_T
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      10_T       11_T       12_T       13_T       14_T       15_T       16_T       17_T       18_T       19_T       20_T
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      21_T       22_T       23_T
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          0         30         60         30          0         36         60         60         60         30
        60          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0
         0          0          0

         2          0          0         48         30          0         60         60          0          0         12
        18         12          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0
         0          0          0


SQL>
SQL>
```

Comment: `to_number(to_char(in_time, 'hh24'))` is better written as `extract(hour from in_time)`. Same for all the rest.

Answer (score 0):

In the solution below, the range_start and range_end dates are hard-coded in a `with` clause (subquery). You can change those, for example, to bind variables, to allow for user input.

In the main query, I create a small table with values from 1 to 12, in the usual way (a `connect by` query), and I use the `pivot` operator to get the results lined up in a single row; `pivot` was introduced in Oracle 11.1, so you most likely can use it, but if your version is older, other methods for pivoting exist, which will work equally well.

The heart of the solution is the math computation in the first part of `pivot`. I won't explain the math here (if it is not obvious), since this is a programming forum, not an arithmetic one.

```
with
  test_data as (
    select to_date('01-JAN-2017', 'dd-MON-yyyy') as range_start,
           to_date('31-MAR-2018', 'dd-MON-yyyy') as range_end
    from   dual
  )
select *
from   (select level as mth from dual connect by level <= 12) 
       cross join test_data
pivot  (min(extract(year from range_end) - extract(year from range_start) + 1
            - case when extract(month from range_start) > mth then 1 else 0 end
            - case when extract(month from range_end)   < mth then 1 else 0 end)
        for mth in (1 jan, 2 feb, 3 mar, 4 apr, 5 may, 6 jun, 7 jul, 8 aug, 9 sep,
                          10 oct, 11 nov, 12 dec))
;
```

**Output**

```
JAN FEB MAR APR MAY JUN JUL AUG SEP OCT NOV DEC
--- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
  2   2   2   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @mathguy. Your code along with Connor's above were very helpful in solving my problem. Cheers man.